# Extracting rows based on the value

Tags: r

I have tab delim text file which contains the following columns:

```
Probe    A_sig  A_Pval  
ILMN_122 12.31   0.04    
ILMN_456 56.12   0      
ILMN_198 981.2   0.06    
ILMN_980 876.0   0.001   
ILMN_542 123.9   0.16     
ILMN_567 134.1   0      
ILMN_452 213.4   0.98     
ILMN_142 543.8   0.04  
ILMN_765 187.4   0.05
```

Now I want to take out those rows which has the Pval <.05. The output should look like

```
     Probe     A_sig   A_Pval  
   ILMN_122     12.31   0.04  
   ILMN_980     876.0   0.001   
   ILMN_142     543.8   0.04
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll answer this but it's a basic question that is probably repeated elsewhere on this list.

Load data.

```
DAT <- read.table(text="Probe    A_sig  A_Pval  
ILMN_122 12.31   0.04   
ILMN_456 56.12   0        
ILMN_198 981.2   0.06   
ILMN_980 876.0   0.001     
ILMN_542 123.9   0.16      
ILMN_567 134.1   0          
ILMN_452 213.4   0.98
ILMN_142 543.8   0.04
ILMN_765 187.4   0.05", h=T)
```

You can use indexing as in:

```
DAT[DAT$A_Pval <.05, ]
```

However this returns the zero vales as well.  That isn't what you're output looks like.  If you don't want the zeros use logical operator & as well as in:

```
DAT[DAT$A_Pval <.05 & DAT$A_Pval!=0, ]
```

I suggest you take a look at some manuals and this [(LINK)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf) reference card to help get you started.

Comment: thank you very much for your help...Now when I have multiple columns like above..how can I get only those rows with pval less than 0.05..plese do help me

Comment: @Thileepan You altered the original question to make a completely new question.  I reproduced you're out put you had before.  If you're original question has been answered mark on the answers here correct and ask your new question in a new thread.  And please return the thread to it's original state as ClodeSlinger and I's responses now do not make sense.

Comment: PS I give you a lot of the information you need to answer this new question in my post above.  Did you look at the reference card?

Comment: Sorry for the inconnvenience..I have restored to the original question and also the other query,I posted as new question.

Answer (score 2):

`my_dataframe[my_dataframe$A_Pval < 0.05,]`

The trailing comma is important.

Comment: and you can read the tab delimited file like this `my_dataframe <- read.delim("tmp.txt", sep='\t', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` assuming the file is in the working directory and named tmp.txt